# R transform output of a loop function from embedded lists to dataframe

Tags: r, loops

I am running a loop to pull data from an API.  Specifically I have a large dataset of species and am using the International Union for Conservation of Nature's API to pull the threats facing 10,000 plus species.  The loop I am using to pull this information is -

```
result <- vector('list', length(df$scientific_name))

for (i in df$scientific_name) {
  result[[i]] <- rl_threats(name=i, key = '1234', parse = TRUE)
}
```

This successfully passes in the species name (scientific name) for i and pulls threats for that species.  However the issue is the output is not particularly usable for me.  The output is a list with 3 layers of nesting like this -

```
>Result
    >Species name
         >Results data frame _by_
```

This output is hard to do analyses on and I would like to transform it into a dataframe

This code below worked to transform individual species in the list into a dataframe, but I need to do this for each of the 10,000 plus species in the dataset.  I am guessing writing a new loop or modifying the above loop would be the best way to do this, but couldn't figure out how to make it work.

```
test1<-data.frame(result[26])
```

Ideal output would be a dataframe that looks like

```
         species name \ threat code \ threat title 
species1
species2
species3
```

Thanks for any help!

Edit-
Per request this is what the output looks like from the dput command

```
dput(head(result))

list(`Myxine glutinosa` = list(name = "Myxine glutinosa", result = structure(list(
    code = c("5.4", "5.4.2"), title = c("Fishing & harvesting aquatic resources", 
    "Intentional use: (large scale) [harvest]"), timing = c("Ongoing", 
    "Ongoing"), scope = c(NA, NA), severity = c(NA, NA), score = c("Low Impact: 3", 
    "Low Impact: 3"), invasive = c(NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1:2)), 
    `Myxine ios` = list(name = "Myxine ios", result = list()), 
    `Lampetra fluviatilis` = list(name = "Lampetra fluviatilis", 
        result = list()), `Lethenteron camtschaticum` = list(
        name = "Lethenteron camtschaticum", result = structure(list(
            code = c("5.4", "5.4.1", "7.2", "7.2.11"), title = c("Fishing & harvesting aquatic resources", 
            "Intentional use: (subsistence/small scale) [harvest]", 
            "Dams & water management/use", "Dams (size unknown)"
            ), timing = c("Ongoing", "Ongoing", "Ongoing", "Ongoing"
            ), scope = c("Unknown", "Unknown", "Unknown", "Unknown"
            ), severity = c("Unknown", "Unknown", "Unknown", 
            "Unknown"), score = c("Unknown", "Unknown", "Unknown", 
            "Unknown"), invasive = c(NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
        4L))), `Petromyzon marinus` = list(name = "Petromyzon marinus", 
        result = list()), `Carcharhinus altimus` = list(name = "Carcharhinus altimus", 
        result = structure(list(code = c("5.4", "5.4.3", "5.4.4"
        ), title = c("Fishing & harvesting aquatic resources", 
        "Unintentional effects: (subsistence/small scale) [harvest]", 
        "Unintentional effects: (large scale) [harvest]"), timing = c("Ongoing", 
        "Ongoing", "Ongoing"), scope = c("Majority (50-90%)", 
        "Majority (50-90%)", "Majority (50-90%)"), severity = c("Slow, Significant Declines", 
        "Slow, Significant Declines", "Slow, Significant Declines"
        ), score = c("Medium Impact: 6", "Medium Impact: 6", 
        "Medium Impact: 6"), invasive = c(NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
        3L))))
```

Comment: Hi Cyph, can you post some of the output to make this a reproducible example? `dput(head(result))` would probably work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like an `lapply` loop works pretty well!

```r
result_list <- lapply(result, function(spec){
  if(length(spec$result)){
    data.frame(species_name=spec$name, threat_code=spec$result$code, threat_title=spec$result$title)
  }
})
result_df <- do.call(what = rbind, result_list)
rownames(result_df) <- NULL
```

[image: output]

Comment: This works, thanks so much!  Would've taken me forever to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `purrr`'s `map_df` :

```
new <- purrr::map_df(result, `[[`, 'result', .id = 'species')
new
#                  species   code                                                      title
#1          Myxine glutinosa    5.4                     Fishing & harvesting aquatic resources
#2          Myxine glutinosa  5.4.2                   Intentional use: (large scale) [harvest]
#3 Lethenteron camtschaticum    5.4                     Fishing & harvesting aquatic resources
#4 Lethenteron camtschaticum  5.4.1       Intentional use: (subsistence/small scale) [harvest]
#5 Lethenteron camtschaticum    7.2                                Dams & water management/use
#6 Lethenteron camtschaticum 7.2.11                                        Dams (size unknown)
#7      Carcharhinus altimus    5.4                     Fishing & harvesting aquatic resources
#8      Carcharhinus altimus  5.4.3 Unintentional effects: (subsistence/small scale) [harvest]
#9      Carcharhinus altimus  5.4.4             Unintentional effects: (large scale) [harvest]

#   timing             scope                   severity            score invasive
#1 Ongoing              <NA>                       <NA>    Low Impact: 3       NA
#2 Ongoing              <NA>                       <NA>    Low Impact: 3       NA
#3 Ongoing           Unknown                    Unknown          Unknown       NA
#4 Ongoing           Unknown                    Unknown          Unknown       NA
#5 Ongoing           Unknown                    Unknown          Unknown       NA
#6 Ongoing           Unknown                    Unknown          Unknown       NA
#7 Ongoing Majority (50-90%) Slow, Significant Declines Medium Impact: 6       NA
#8 Ongoing Majority (50-90%) Slow, Significant Declines Medium Impact: 6       NA
#9 Ongoing Majority (50-90%) Slow, Significant Declines Medium Impact: 6       NA
```

You can then `select` and keep only the columns that you want from `new`.